# combination of "res.sendFile" at expressjs middleware and "ng-src" at angular client does not work

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to create user profile with an avatar picture; I have uploaded the avatar picture successfully using multer; now I am trying to provider an option to edit the profile; as part of this edit, I have to display the avatar picture at the client; I have written a service in the middleware to return the avatar image using res.sendFile;

Middleware controller:

```
exports.readAvatar = function(req, res) {
    if (req.user) {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + "/../../uploads/" + req.user.avatar));
    }
}
```

I have even tested this service from a browser and is working successfully but when I tried to display the response of this avatar service using ng-src with data url like below, it did not work.

Client controller:

```
Users.avatar($routeParams.userId).then(function(data) {
    $scope.avatar = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+data;
}, function(errorResponse) {
    $scope.error = errorResponse.message
});
```

Html:

```
   <img data-ng-src="{{avatar}}" >
```

When I googled, I found that res.sendFile is actually sending a byte stream; so I tried to convert that into a string, then encoded the converted string and used this encoded string in ng-src but to no avail. any help will be appreciated/

Comment: What does your data contain? It probably must be data.data

Comment: @Vivz, data contains the bytestream returned by res.sendFile;data looks like this "Resource {0: "�", 1: "�", 2: "�", 3: "�", 4: " ", 5: "", 6: "J", 7: "F", 8: "I", 9: "F", 10: ".."   indexes are there till 68889

Comment: you have to pass the path to an image file in avatar variable.

Comment: @VivZ, why so? this is not static image to be made available through URL; I am thinking to return a bytes or encoded string; if I am not right, can you help how to return the path to display the image?

Comment: I know that it is not a static image but you can return a dynamic array of urls pointing to your images from your API. Idk if bytes or an encoded string will work. You have to check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc.

Comment: Thanks @Vivz, that worked! I was not required to hit the middleware from the controller but having this ng-src="/users/{{user._id}}/avatar" itself sufficed! Please add your comment as answer!

Comment: I have added an answer below. Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the correct path value to `ng-src`.

**JS**

```
Users.avatar($routeParams.userId).then(function(response) {
    //capture whatever is necessary to show image
    $scope.user=response.data;
}, function(errorResponse) {
    $scope.error = errorResponse.message
});
```

**HTML**

```
<img ng-src="/users/{{user._id}}/avatar">
```

**For more Info**: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc